How can I move a subdirectory to overwrite the parent directory?
Let's say I run,
cd /tmp/
mkdir -p foo/bar/
echo test > foo/bar/1

Now I have a very simple
$ tree foo
foo
└── bar
    └── 1

2 directories, 1 file

Now if I want to move foo/bar to overwrite foo, such that the tree looks like
$ tree foo
foo
└── 1

1 directories, 1 file

What command can I run? When I try mv, I get 'foo/bar' and 'foo/bar' are the same file
mv foo/bar foo
mv: 'foo/bar' and 'foo/bar' are the same file

Does Linux not support this? Is this a limitation of GNU mv?

Unix mv never supported overwriting a  directory. See e.g. https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/mv/

@reinierpost I've been using Linux since 1998, as a daily driver. I go Linux Users Group weekly. I work at a company building Linux system admin tools. I guess I never wanted to do this, and just assumed it always worked. Certainly took me shock. I thought in without the trailing / mv would treat both SRC and DEST as files and just replace the INODE in the directory listing and delete the other entry. However useless, TIL.

@reinierpost added your link in my answer

Does this answer your question? How to move and overwrite subdirectories (and files) to parent directory?

@muru that question is "I have a ton of files and dirs in a subdirectory I want to move to the parent directory" that's why all the answers use rsync. This question is replacing a single parent directory with one directory which is a subdirectory.

No direct invocation of mv supports this
I could be wrong, but it seems to be impossible and that UNIX System V mv never supported this either. I worked around this by making a tempdir with mktemp so I could delete the parent dir entirely.
cd /tmp/
PARENT=foo
CHILD=bar
TEMP=$(mktemp -d)
mv "$PARENT/$CHILD" "$TEMP"
rm -rf "$PARENT"
mv "$TEMP/$CHILD" $PARENT

Seems anytime the destination is a directory, mv moves the source into the destination rather than overwriting the destination. This is a deviation from the underlying rename function in C which supports this. But the underlying rename function in C does NOT support moving a source to a destination if the destination is a directory that is NOT empty, you'll get the perror.

rename: Directory not empty

If you try.

Good, cheers! ;)

The mv command takes two forms (excluding options):
mv SOURCE DEST
mv SOURCE... DIRECTORY

The first form only works if DEST does not exist or is not a directory.  If it is not a directory, it deletes it first.
In all other cases, including if the second parameter is an existing directory or if there are multiple sources, it assumes you want to move the source(s) into the directory.  If there are multiple sources and the last item is not a directory, you get an error.
If this isn't what you want, make sure DEST doesn't exist.
set up:
cd /tmp/
mkdir -p foo/bar/
echo test > foo/bar/1

your desired restruture:
mv foo/bar newfoo
rmdir foo
mv newfoo foo

There's no way around this.  The mv command doesn't support overwriting directories.

If newfoo already exists, you'll get a surprise.  Answering what that surprise would be would make this answer recursive.

the same information I provided below, except without a tmpdir to stop that surprise.

The error makes sense to me! You're trying to move "bar" to the directory "foo", but it already is in directory "foo".
would seem to me you just wanted to
cd /tmp
mv foo/bar .


Close, this moves it to /tmp/bar, not /tmp/foo.

but that seems to be what you wanted, no? You can afterwards still rmdir foo; mv bar foo if you really wanted to give it the same name!

Simply use:
mv foo/bar/1 foo/1
rmdir foo/bar

rmdir will fail if the directory is not empty, which avoids inadvertently removing other files.

$ find foo --type f -exec mv {} foo \;
$ rm -rf foo/bar

